# Laravel - include few views in one with controllers

Tags: laravel, view

Im working on Laravel and i have problem.

I created two controllers: PostController - has a view and PostController has a view.

I created next Controller called HomeController and i want to execute both Controller here PostController and MyProfileController.

I created a method in HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    $profile_view = app('App\Http\Controllers\MyProfileController')->index();
    $post_view = app('App\Http\Controllers\PostController')->index();

    return view('home',
        [
            'profile_view' => $profile_view,
            'post_view' => $post_view
        ]
    );
}
```

And im trying to show in view (home.blade.php)

```
@extends('layout')
@section('main-content')

Something

{!! $profile_view !!}
{!! $post_view !!}

@endsection
```

and it is viewing only one view from $post_view. 
Anyone has a idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another view that would use `®include` to do that and refer that view from your controller.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: but @include doesn't work with controllers. I must to connect Controller with view, not only view

Comment: @include is part of blade templating so ot will work. See updated answer.

Comment: I have a few views with data from Controller and when i'm only including view i have error with not existing variable.

Comment: I gave you **complete** answer but you did not even try to read the page I linked to.

Comment: @include('view.name', ['some' => 'data']) It is not good solution for me i think

Comment: What is told you you cannot pass variable? Put more efforts

Comment: i added new answer